# composite email framework velocity

Tags: translation, velocity, partials

I have application which is built in Spring MVC. This uses Velocity email templates. But hard to manage various templates for different languages.

Is there a way to combine headers, footers and main email body into a COMPOSITE template and then use the elements within this email structure using velocity.

This composite should provide translation also

Comment: Are you searching for the [parse](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#parse) element? With this, you can separate the common parts of your velocity in different files and include then in many velocity files.

Comment: not exactly parse element, however yes we can use with it. Also translation thing is main where i want to translate the messages using some inline code